# Can't compile with BibTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, bibtex, errors

I'm creating a document in LaTeX with the bibliography in a separated BibTeX file.

When I compile the document without any reference to the bibliography it runs correctly, but when I add references to the bibliography it sends the following error.

```
! You can't use `the character 1' after \the.
```

I was making some tests and when I remove the `tikzpicture`, the whole file compiles correctly, including the bibliography. But when I add the picture again, I get the same error.

The following code is a sample with the image that triggers the error.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
%Si se activa no funcionan algunos gráficos
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,backgrounds,arrows,intersections}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{verbatim}



\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
%\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{cancel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %para que ponga 1.1.1.1 en subsubsecciones
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que ponga subsubsecciones en el indice

\usepackage{titlesec}

\graphicspath{ {imagenes/} }

\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[display] % shape
{\bfseries\Large\itshape} % format
{}
%{Story No. \ \thechapter} % label
{0.5ex} % sep
{
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} % before-code
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}%
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
] % after-code

\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}


\begin{document}

\title{Apuntes y Tareas de Probabilidad.}
\author{Luis Alejandro Barranco Ju\'arez}


\maketitle

%\begin{titlepage}
%\begin{center}
%\begin{Huge}
%\textsc{Apuntes y Tareas.}
%\end{Huge}
%\end{center}
%\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents % indice de contenidos

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Tarea 1} 
\markboth{TAREA 1}{TAREA 1}

\section{Tri\'angulos de Pascal.}   

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=13mm,y=9mm]
    % some colors
    \colorlet{even}{cyan!60!black}
    \colorlet{odd}{orange!100!black}
    \colorlet{links}{red!70!black}
    \colorlet{back}{yellow!20!white}
    % some styles
    \tikzset{
            box/.style={
            minimum height=5mm,
            inner sep=.7mm,
            outer sep=0mm,
            text width=10mm,
            text centered,
            font=\small\bfseries\sffamily,
            text=#1!50!black,
            draw=#1,
            line width=.25mm,
            top color=#1!5,
            bottom color=#1!40,
            shading angle=0,
            rounded corners=2.3mm,
            drop shadow={fill=#1!40!gray,fill opacity=.8},
            rotate=0,
            },
            link/.style={-latex,links,line width=.3mm},
            plus/.style={text=links,font=\footnotesize\bfseries\sffamily},
    }
    % Pascal's triangle
    % row #0 => value is 1
    \node[box=odd] (p-0-0) at (0,0) {1};
    \foreach \row in {1,...,16} {
     % col #0 =&gt; value is 1
            \node[box=odd] (p-\row-0) at (-\row/2,-\row) {1};
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\value}{1};
            \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
        % iterative formula : val = precval * (row-col+1)/col
        % (+ 0.5 to bypass rounding errors)
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\value}{\value*((\row-\col+1)/\col)+0.5};
            \global\let\value=\value
            % position of each value
            \coordinate (pos) at (-\row/2+\col,-\row);
            % odd color for odd value and even color for even value
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rest}{mod(\value,5)}
            \ifnum \rest=0
                    \node[box=even] (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {\value};
            \else
                    \node[box=odd] (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {\value};
            \fi
      % for arrows and plus sign
%      \ifnum \col<\row
%        \node[plus,above=0mm of p-\row-\col]{+};
%        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prow}{\row-1}
%        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pcol}{\col-1}
%        \draw[link] (p-\prow-\pcol) -- (p-\row-\col);
%        \draw[link] ( p-\prow-\col) -- (p-\row-\col);
%      \fi
            }
    }
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            % filling and drawing with the same color to enlarge background
            \path[draw=back,fill=back,line width=5mm,rounded corners=2.5mm]
            (  p-0-0.north west) -- (  p-0-0.north east) --
            (p-16-16.north east) -- (p-16-16.south east) --
            ( p-16-0.south west) -- ( p-16-0.north west) --
            cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Para n=5.

    \cite{Polya}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
\bibliographystyle{acm} % estilo de la bibliografía.
\bibliography{prueba} % biblio.bib es el fichero donde está salvada la bibliografía.

\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file looks like this:

```
@book{Polya,
author    = "G.Polya",
title     = "How to Solve It",
publisher = "Princeton University Press",
year      = "1957",
}
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable!  Then we can copy your code and test on our own computers ... Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you, I have modified the post with a sample of my code with the elements that are not compiling correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I have run the code for the tikz picture and it works fine, but when I add the link to the bibliography, the file doesn't compile.

Comment: Have you checked the log files for warnings? If there are warnings check all of them! They can cause/explain the problem. Add the tikz code only if it is error and warning free ...

Comment: Please consider minimising your code. If you have a really simple picture, does the problem still occur? Does it go away if you don't load `cancel`? If not, you don't need `cancel` in the example. You should also consider cleaning up your preamble for your own sake. You have a lot of redundant stuff there which will only make troubleshooting harder.

Comment: Don't use `\value`. Use e.g. `\myvalue` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *Thoughtless use of `\def`, `\let`, `\global` etc. costs lives.*

Well, they waste time, anyway, and if you waste enough of that, that's a life gone.

---

You have overridden TeX's definition of `\value` and made this redefinition global by saying

```
\global\let\value=\value
```

TeX is, therefore, unable to do anything which depends on `\value` after this point in the document. The citation is just collateral damage.

Here's a not minimal, but at least more minimal, example which reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\ifnum\value{page}=1 hi\else bye\fi

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \row in {1,...,16} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\value}{1}
    \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\value}{\value*((\row-\col+1)/\col)+0.5};
      \global\let\value=\value
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\ifnum\value{page}=1 hi\else bye\fi
\end{document}
```

The problem can be addressed by ensuring that new macro names do not overwrite existing ones. In this case, substituting `\myvalue` for `\value` will work.

Using `\newcommand*\value{1}` rather than `\pgfmathsetmacro{\value}{1}` would have provided an informative error message explaining the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: @labj86 Croeso! (You're welcome!)